# Notifications still received even with no trigger event

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I'm still receiving API notifications such as "31/07/20 06:45   createTimeDrivenTriggers    Exception: Ce script comprend trop de déclencheurs. Veuillez supprimer certains d'entre eux avant d'en ajouter d'autres.    time-based  31/07/20 06:45", even after having cleared any API project.
Can you please help me to fix this problem ?
Thank you
jean-louis

Answer (score 2):

Create a new spreadsheet file, click on Tools -> Script editor and then after the new tab loads click on Resources and then all triggers. There you can find the triggers of all your projects and you can delete the ones you don't want.
I translated the message you are getting and it seems you have too many triggers for this particular project. Please check the [quotas page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) for more details :

> Only 20 triggers are allowed per user/per script.

[image: See more info here]

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://script.google.com/home/triggers

There you will find all the Google Apps Script triggers for your account. Delete those that you don't want.

Even if you don't have any Google Apps Script project you could still have triggers i.e. you installed a G Suite or G Suite Editor add-on which create a trigger.